# UIPasteboard image cannot be inserted in Notes.app ios8

Tags: ios, custom-keyboard, uipasteboard

I am copying image using this code

```
[[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] setImage:myImage];
```

I can then insert this image in other programs including notes.app in ios9 or any other app in ios 8. But i can't insert it in notes.app on iOs 8.

I can manually copy image from Photos.app or via other custom keyboards, like Advertising emojis and insert it, what should i change in my code to support Notes.app on ios 8 ?

Comment: What is the format of the UIImage?

Comment: It's simple Png image 512x512 pixels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use this code

```
[[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] setData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) forPasteboardType:@"public.png"];
```

This will definitely solve your issue, and image will insert in all application with paste image functionality.

Comment: will try in a moment, ty